# Adding target to UIButton for superview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, skscene

I am adding a `UIView` programatically to an `SKScene`. In this `UIView` I have a button that should fire a command in the `SKScene`. How do I do this? My code throws an exception. Or perhaps this is just not clean programming?

```
class LevelAchievedView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.opaque = false
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let replayButton = UIButton()
        replayButton.setTitle("Replay?", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        replayButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        replayButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 30)
        replayButton.addTarget(self.superview, action: "returnToStart", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        replayButton.frame.origin = CGPointMake(10, 10)
        self.addSubview(replayButton)
    }
```

It seems I am messing up `replayButton.addTarget(self.superview...` and I guess I cannot use self.superview in this case although I have the `func returnToStart()` in the SKScene. What am I missing?

The exception thrown:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKView returnToStart]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff10980fc00'
```

Comment: I think you have created `returnToStart` in your `SKScene` class. But `self.superview` is not the `SKScene`, simply because `SKScene` is not a subclass of `UIView`. Your code try to execute `returnToStart` on the `UIView` received by `didMoveToView(view: UIView)`. Also not that `returnToStart` != `returnToStart:`.

Comment: Yes I have created returnToStart in my SKScene class. Can I access the SKScene functions from the UIView?

Comment: I posted a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.superview` is not the `SKScene`. Just a solution:

```
class LevelAchievedView: UIView {
    let replayButton: UIButton

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.replayButton = UIButton()

        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.opaque = false

        replayButton.setTitle("Replay?", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        replayButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        replayButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 30)
        replayButton.frame.origin = CGPointMake(10, 10)
        self.addSubview(replayButton)
    }
}

class MyScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        // ...
        let levelAchieved = LevelAchievedView(rect: CGRect(...))
        levelAchieved.replayButton.addTarget(self, action: "returnToStart", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(levelAchieved)
    }

    func returnToStart() {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use this code I get the message: Property 'self.replayButton' not initialized at super.init call.

Comment: I updated my code. But I think you was able to fix that. Please don't only copy-paste...

Comment: I changed the second line to 'let replayButton = UIButton()' and deleted the 'self.replayButton = UIButton'. Works perfectly now, thanks a million!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement returnToStart. Try adding something like this:

```
function returnToStart() {
    println("returning to start");
}
```

to your `LevelAchevedView` class

Comment: When I do that I cannot change the SKView that contains the UIView LevelAchievedView class. So it does not work for me.